# Update the position of a JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

**How can I get my program to realize that the boundaries of the JFrame have changed?**

I have a JFrame, declared with:

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("My Rad and Sick Pong Game");
myFrame.setSize(1024,768);
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

I also have a method that only makes the game play when the mouse is over the JFrame,

```
boolean mouseOnScreen = false;
Point zero = myFrame.getLocationOnScreen();
int zeroX = (int) zero.getX();
int zeroY = (int) zero.getY();
if (mouseX > zeroX && mouseX < zeroX + getWidth()){
    if (mouseY > zeroY && mouseY < zeroY + getHeight()){
        mouseOnScreen = true;
    }
}
return mouseOnScreen;
```

This works well when the JFrame is in the same position that it started in, stretching from (0,0) to (1024,768). However, if it is moved, the boundaries of the JFrame don't change, so my mouse is "off the JFrame" even when it's still inside, because it hasn't realized the JFrame was moved.

I thought the `myFrame.getLocationOnScreen` would make it work but it doesn't.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Notes:

- I'm using Netbeans 8.1
- When I resize the JFrame the paddles of my pong game move to the edges, so some parts of the program realize the size has changed.

**EDIT: Added more code:**

My main code:

```
    running = false;
    repaint();
    while (mouseOnScreen(mouseY, mouseX, myFrame)) //Update Game
    {
        //Mouse Code        
        PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point b = a.getLocation();
        mouseY = (int) b.getY();
        mouseX = (int) b.getX();

        //Run
        repaint();
        running = true;
        moveBall();
        movePaddle(mouseY);
        moveEnemyPaddle();

        //Code to sleep for 30ms to allow time for execution was here
        }
    }

private boolean mouseOnScreen(int mouseX, int mouseY, JFrame myFrame) {
    boolean mouse = false;
    Point zero = myFrame.getLocationOnScreen();
    int zeroX = (int) zero.getX();
    int zeroY = (int) zero.getY();
    if (mouseX > zeroX && mouseX < zeroX + getWidth()) {
        if (mouseY > zeroY && mouseY < zeroY + getHeight()) {
            mouse = true;
        }
    }
    return mouse;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    //(my other drawing stuff was here, removed because irrelevant)
    if (!running) {
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

I believe that is everything relevant. Thanks for your time so far guys!

Comment: `"I thought the myFrame.getLocationOnScreen would make it work but it doesn't"` -- it would work if it's called each time it is needed, likely inside of your MouseListener, but if you call it only once, it would be useless. As it is, it's impossible to see how you're using it based on the code you've posted. Don't force us to guess -- create and post a viable [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried using `MouseListener.mouseEntered / mouseExited?`

Comment: @ControlAltDel: he'd potentially have a problem if any sub components, such as a JButton or text component stole the mouse from the listened to component.

Comment: Mouse events or contextual to the component which created them, have you translated the mouse event to the screen coordinate space?

Comment: I don't have a MouseListener. I've been getting my mouse position with           `PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point b = a.getLocation();
            mouseY = (int) b.getY() - 38;
            mouseX = (int) b.getX();`

Comment: Also, @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, because I'm constantly checking the mouse position, isn't that also calling `myFrame.getLocationOnScreen`?

Comment: @Tim: Without your showing pertinent code as previously requested, preferably a valid [mcve] (again, please read the link), who the hell knows what your code is doing?

Comment: ***"EDIT: Added more code:"*** No, post an MCVE as first requested. Please read and try to understand the linked document.